# Google Analytics - Can anyone explain Dimensions and Metrics?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I've implemented the new Google Analytics library (2.0) for iOS for app tracking. Tracking views etc is very simple, but I'm having trouble understanding how to use Dimensions and Metrics.

I've read the documentation multiple times but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around it.

Basically, I want to check how many of my users have a specific setting enabled when using the app.

In semipseudo-code, this is what I'd like to do:

```
- (void)applicationLaunched
{
    id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"My ID"];

    if (_mySettingIsEnabled) {
        [tracker setUserValue:@"Enabled" forKey:@"My Setting"];
    } else {
        [tracker setUserValue:@"Disabled" forKey:@"My Setting"];
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain to me how I would do this per user with Dimensions and Metrics?

Answer (score 2):

Check the official documentation: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/customdimsmets

- Make sure you have a new property (GA is organized in Account/Property/Profiles, so click on the "home", than an account, than add a new app property) - I had an older property/profile and nothing was working with the IOS GA library 2.0.
- Register on the GA web, open a Property, there will be a tab for Custom Definitions, where you can register custom dimensions and metrics - Lets say "AppMode", which is the custom definition with index 1.
- Set the custom dimension/metric value in your code:

  ```
  NSString *appMode = @"Demo";
  [_gaiTracker setCustom:1 dimension:appMode];
  ```

Comment: here's the newer version
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/customdimsmets

Comment: and for Javascript https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you might go with [custom variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables#visitorLevel).

Having a specific setting enabled might either be on user or on session level, so you should set the scope to either 1 or 2. The setting you want to track is value of your custom var or the "dimension", and depending on the scope you get the metrics # of users or # of visits automatically.

in JS that looks like

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar',
      1,                // This custom var is set to slot #1.  Required parameter.
      'My Setting',    // The name of the custom variable.  Required parameter.
      'Disabled',        // The value of the custom variable.  Required parameter.
                        //  (possible values might be Free, Bronze, Gold, and Platinum)
      1                 // Sets the scope to visitor-level.  Optional parameter.
 ]);
```

Comment: This is true for web tracking, but custom variables doesn't exist in the iOS library, so basically I'm asking how to apply the same principle to custom metrics and dimensions

Comment: not familiar to that one, but what i found is this resource: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/devguide#usingCustomVariables